# Gtest_main _dir not found while installing libqi for ros-nao

Tags: ros

I am trying to install libqi for nao-ros and it gives me error: I already have gtest package but gtest_main is missing.

CMake Error at /home/shruti/d-prefix/share/cmake/qibuild/internal/uselib.cmake:80 (find_package): By not providing "FindGTEST_MAIN.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "GTEST_MAIN", but CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "GTEST_MAIN" with any of the following names:

GTEST_MAINConfig.cmake
 gtest_main-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "GTEST_MAIN" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "GTEST_MAIN_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "GTEST_MAIN" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

Any one knows about it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying to build libqi and fixed it by:

```
cd /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules
ln -s FindGTest.cmake FindGTEST_MAIN.cmake
```